# null space of a matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am studying about robotics grasping and I came across null space, which I am not clear about. $$$$

1. The null space of a matrix, $A$, $N(A)$ is the vector $x$ such that $A⋅x=0$. If $x$ is zero vector only, then the solution is said to be trivial, if solutions other than zero exists, they are called non-trivial solutions right? $$$$
2. What does $N(A) \ne 0$ mean? Does it mean that there are non-trivial solutions also? $$$$
3. What does it mean when we say there exists $N(A)$? Does it mean it we have trivial solutions or non-trivial solutions?

Comment: $N(A)\neq 0$ means that there are vectors $x$ other then $0$ such  that  makes $Ax=0$

Comment: The null space is the collection of all vectors $x$ where Ax=0, it is not the vectors themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Yes, but $N(A)$ is a vector space (a set of vectors with vector space structure, not just a vector unless $N(A)=\{\vec{0}\}$).

2.) If $N(A)\neq 0$, it means you have non-trivial solutions to $Ax=0$ which is the same as saying $x\to Ax$ is not one-to-one

3.) $N(A)$ is always non-empty: there is always at least one vector (the zero vector) that maps to $\vec{0}$. This is why the zero vector is called a trivial solution. There are a lot of equivalent ways of saying $Ax=0$ has trivial/non-trivial solutions. For example, $Ax=0$ having only trivial solution (only $x=\vec{0}$ satisfies it) if and only if $A$ is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

The null space always exists. It may be reduced to $0$ or not. If it is reduced to $0$, we have only trivial solutions.

As an $(n\times n)$ matrix is the matrix of a linear map from $\mathbf R^n$ into itself (an *endomorphism* of $\mathbf R^n$), saying the null space of $A$ is $0$ means the linear map is injective (hence bijective). Incicentally, the null space, in terms of linear maps, is usually known as the *kernel* of the linear map.